# Scaling Waveform from LeCroy 4104HD using Python/IEEE488.2

Tags: oscilloscope, python, scpi

I am automating control of a LeCroy oscilloscope using IEEE488.2 and Python/PyVisa.

It seems like it should be relatively straightforward. I use the *WF?* command to get the waveform + header, I use the *Template?* command to get the template for interpreting the header, and then I convert the proper 4 byte fields to floats to get the VERTICAL GAIN and VERTICAL OFFSET.

The problem is that this gives me a scaling factor that doesn't match what I see on the oscilloscope screen. In this link I have a picture of the scope screen, an xlsx with the Template/Header/Waveform responses, and the Python code I used to put those responses in the xlsx -> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FGZZ_1fbPYiSIDmTUJg3PWhE15W3i1KR/view?usp=sharing

Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong? It seems this should be really easy.

Edited: Including pictures of scope picture and my scaled waveform.[image: Scope Picture][image: Scaled Waveform from xlsx]

Comment: Can you attach the picture to the question? There is an image button if you edit the question. You can even copy and paste the image in.

Comment: Pictures are added

Answer (score 1):

The value is a left justified 12bit Q8 number. I suppose I should have noticed the factor of 4 in the pictures.